# Can't Run ASP.NET Core on Centos7(Apache)

Tags: apache, asp.net-core, centos7, kestrel-http-server

For some reasons I can't make Apache work with Kestrel.

Kestrel/Service is Running

```
● kestrel-hellomvc.service - TestTwo Example
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/kestrel-hellomvc.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2017-06-28 02:35:14 UTC; 25min ago
 Main PID: 2182 (dotnet)
   CGroup: /system.slice/kestrel-hellomvc.service
           └─2182 /usr/local/bin/dotnet /var/www/applications/TestOne/TestOne.dll

Jun 28 02:35:14 abcidee systemd[1]: Started TestTwo Example.
Jun 28 02:35:14 abcidee systemd[1]: Starting TestTwo Example...
Jun 28 02:35:15 abcidee dotnet-TestTwo[2182]: Hosting environment: Production
Jun 28 02:35:15 abcidee dotnet-TestTwo[2182]: Content root path: /var/www/applications/TestOne
Jun 28 02:35:15 abcidee dotnet-TestTwo[2182]: Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
Jun 28 02:35:15 abcidee dotnet-TestTwo[2182]: Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
Jun 28 02:35:56 abcidee dotnet-TestTwo[2182]: warn: Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.DataProtectionServices[59]
Jun 28 02:35:56 abcidee dotnet-TestTwo[2182]: Neither user profile nor HKLM registry available. Using an ephemeral key repository. Protected data will be unavailable when application exits.
Jun 28 02:35:56 abcidee dotnet-TestTwo[2182]: warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.EphemeralXmlRepository[50]
Jun 28 02:35:56 abcidee dotnet-TestTwo[2182]: Using an in-memory repository. Keys will not be persisted to storage.
```

Port 5001 on httpd

```
httpd -S
AH00558: httpd: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 10.0.0.4. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
VirtualHost configuration:
*:5001                 10.0.0.4 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/hellomvc.conf:1)
*:443                  10.0.0.4 (/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:56)
```

hellomvc.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:5001>
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://localhost:5000/ retry=0 timeout=5
        ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:5000/
        ServerName hostname.example.com
        ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-error.log
        CustomLog /var/log/httpd/hellomvc-access.log common </VirtualHost>
```

However I am getting

**$curl localhost:5001**

**curl: (7) Failed connect to localhost:5001; Connection refused**

Comment: Looks like it's listening on port 5000 but you've got something (Apache?) proxying to 5001? Can you access on 5000?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm using Centos 7, with Centos Web Panel, => Apache Setting => Edit Apache vHosts or /usr/local/apache/conf.d/vhosts.conf

```
Listen 8081
NameVirtualHost *:8081
<VirtualHost *:8081>
        ProxyRequests Off
        ProxyPreserveHost On
        ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:5000/
        ServerName localdomain
        ServerAlias localdomain
</VirtualHost>
```